# How to have Github do `git diff ..` (two dots) instead of `git diff ...` (three dots)

Tags: git

Assume I have two branches, `master` and `feature`.

The goal is to have a visual way to see the entire diff between `master` and `feature` on Github. This is not possible by default because Github uses `git diff ...` (three dots), which takes the most recent common ancestor when doing diffs between two branches. This means diffs that were introduced into `master` after that common parent will not show up in the diff with `feature`, hence making the diff wrong.

I am looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Do you understand what a rebase does? Why do you think that it would override all changes?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't think it would, I *need* it to though. I'm looking for something like `git merge -s ours`. The end goal is updating what the common ancestor is between `master` and `feature`. So I want to pull all changes from master to feature, then essentially override all common files between `master` and `feature` with the 'feature' version.

Comment: so, you want to get rid of modifications to files that you had changed on **your** branch that has _also_ been modified on master after the branches diverged (and those files, you want them to be as they are at the current tip of master), is that right?

Comment: @eftshift0 I want `feature` branch to be the authoritative one. Anything that is modified/added/removed in master should NOT affect `feature`. I just want to update the common ancestor to be the `HEAD` of `master` for `feature` branch (since `master will clearly be updated constantly). Not sure how to explain it better. I would need a `git merge -s theirs` while on the `feature` branch (but this doesn't exist, as `theirs` is NOT the opposite of `ours` according to the docs.

Comment: Is the feature modifies file which master has why not just merge?

Comment: If I understand correctly, maybe you could identify the first commit on `feature` branch which is not present on `master` branch. Then checkout the tree from that commit (`git checkout $FIRST_COMMIT_ON_FEATURE -- .`). This should remove all changes that were introduced on master since the merge-base. Then you should be able to cherry pick the remaining commits from `feature` branch: `git cherry-pick $FIRST_COMMIT_ON_FEATURE..feature`. This seems quite silly though. Not sure why you'd want to do something like that. If you don't want the changes from master, maybe its better to just not rebase?

Comment: @evolutionxbox If we assume I am in `feature` and I want to merge `master` into `feature`, a simple `git merge master` will bring 1) conflicts and 2) will combine the same file with no warning in case there is no actual conflict. What I want is for `feature` to always be the version of files the "merge" would pick in all occasions, conflict or no conflict.

Comment: @Alderath like I said, the whole purpose of this is so that the common ancestor between `feature` and `master` gets updated so git pulls on github show the correct diff.

Comment: Then why branch? Commit directly to master?

Comment: I need to keep a constant diff between master and the branch in a visual way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the *actual* answer which people here seem not to want to give. Please use at your own risk.

Assuming we want to update the common ancestor between `master` branch and `feature` branch, proceed as follows:

1. Go to `master` and `git pull --rebase` to make sure you have the latest master.
2. Create a branch off `master` with `git branch -b temp_master`
3. Checkout `feature` branch and from here, run `git merge -s ours temp_master`
4. You can now delete `temp_master` and push `feature` with `git push -f origin feature`

Your git pull request is now going to display correct diffs.

Comment: You would never be able to submit such a pull request to an upstream repo. Because your commit is now essentially removing all changes from the upstream master. At some point, before you submit the pull request, you would **need** to properly resolve the conflicts.

Comment: @Alderath like I said, the purpose of this is to just show the diffs on github as doing `git diff master..feature`, which github doesn't do by default.

Comment: The reason people might "not want to give" this answer is likely because it only thinks of the current repo. Who'd want to contribute to a repo if the owner is only going to completely wipe out any changes except their own?

Answer (score 4):

To show two dot diff on github:

1. Open diff view page between `master` and `feature`. The UI changes all the time, but in the end your url should look something like this: https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/compare/master...feature
2. Change three points to two points in the page url
3. Profit!

There is the official documentation on github - [Three-dot and two-dot Git diff comparisons](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests#three-dot-and-two-dot-git-diff-comparisons)

You can use branch names or hash right in url.
By default, master vs local branch comparison opens as a short url like https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/compare/feature. Just add `master..` to url.

Comment: This is not helpful at all, the article doesn't say how to set two-dot diff for a project, it just tells you how to compare 2 commits and that you can change the url to see two-dot diff.

Comment: @GeorgePandurov Yes, yet cannot be set by default, nevertheless this is the answer to the question. Topicstarer asked how to do it in general

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you don't really want a feature branch.  If you are sure you always want to overwrite Master, then just commit directly to Master.  **But I wouldn't recommend this unless you are the only person working in this repository.**

If you want to see the diff between commits, see [Comparing commits](https://help.github.com/en/articles/comparing-commits-across-time#comparing-commits)
or [Comparisons across commits](https://help.github.com/en/articles/comparing-commits-across-time#comparisons-across-commits)